# Should I just have the needed environment or environment+the application itself in a Docker image

Tags: docker, jenkins

I've been playing with Docker for the last 5 days. And now that I'm comfortable with it, I wonder if I should put my application, e.g a war file, right when building it, in other words ADD it inside the Dockerfile, or I should just generate an image that will provide the necessary environment for my application? Is there a best practice? The second option seems to make more sense, If, for example you won't to automate the build and deployment in Jenkins. But still I would like to know.

Comment: Usually it is recommended to let the pipeline to build the image as the Dockerfile should be at the root of of your source code (or use a pattern for Dockerfile directory according to your organizational needs).

Comment: Oh, you mean I should have the Dockerfile as part of my application project. Never thought that way.

Comment: Yes, the same way we put `Jenkinsfile` at the root of our project.